# Distinguishing multiple view instances by Id (numerical) vs separate, uniquely named layout files

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I'm currently instantiating multiple instances of view by inflating from a single layout file RecordNoteBox.axml

**RecordNoteBox.axml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<app.droid.views.custom.PagedFragmentRecordNoteBox
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:id="@+id/rb_record_note_box"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="#FF555555">
```

Since I didn't specifically set each instance's Id (numerical) to a unique, non-zero value, they are all referring to the same instance, and so changing the contents through one reference causes them so show up in all the other "screen copies" of the view (for lack of a better term).

Which is the preferred method, for performance reasons

(A) To set each instance's .Id value to a unique value (integer)

```
static int _idCount = 1;

View box1 = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecordNoteBox, null);
View box2 = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecordNoteBox, null);

box1 = _idCount++;
box2 = _idCount++;
```

(B) Make multiple copies of the layout file, giving each one a specific name

```
View box1 = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecordNoteBox1, null);
View box2 = _inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecordNoteBox2, null);
```

Or does it really even matter ?  Thanks!

Comment: The objects are not the same instance. Do not worry about it.

Comment: They are not the same instance in straight java-android ? Could the mono runtime be the source of my issue ?

Comment: i suspect the implementation of `PagedFragmentRecordNoteBox` would be the issue, but can't say for sure.

Comment: CB & jm, I'm having serious issues with this... I'm either going to have to translate the layout file into a class and instantiate, or copy and paste multiple layoutfiles, each having a unique id string. I'm serious dude, its totally not working!

Comment: @j__m I will look into it, but I don't really see how subclassing a view changes anything wrt id(entity) strings. I will make a sample program, all with native, un-subclassed views, b/c you have instilled doubt.

Comment: You are doing something wrong. Because Inflation instantiates a new View hierarchy every time, so none of the objects should be a reference to the same View, unless you somehow has managed to make your `RecordNoteBox` a singleton.

Comment: @Cheesebaron I just got real quick and dirty with it and employed (B). Copied and pasted the RecordNoteBox.axml layout file, giving each one its own name, and own unique id-string and called it a day.  I will return to this when I have more time (riiiight). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ids only matter if you are using `findViewById()`, which you don't need to do here since you already have references to the individual views.  I wouldn't bother doing either A or B.